# How can Quickly create new milestones/releases and upload tarball files to Launchpad?

Tags: quickly, development

Quickly has the tendency of messing with some of the source code files (e.g. the files in debian/, licence stuff and so...), so at time it is necessary to manually save/share/release/submitubuntu (if not even run!). I think I'd be nice if this issue might be solved in future releases of quickly, for I believe that this is a problem for many Ubuntu Developers.

Meanwhile my question is: how can one manually reproduce the steps performed by "quickly submitubuntu" via the command line? In particular, I'm referring to the creation of a new milestone, turning it into a release, and uploading download files into it.

I tried looking at quickly source code, but I found it hard to follow all those methods from different modules in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly would be using the Launchpad API to perform those actions.

To manually do them, you can go to the project page on Launchpad, go to the series you wish to create the milestone/release on (likely trunk if you don't have multiple series to manage), and choose the "Create Milestone" or "Create Release" links on the page. Creating a release requires the creation of a new milestone if one doesn't exist, and you can do that from the create release UI. If a milestone already exists, you can go to the page for that specific milestone, and click "Release now" on it, or from the list of milestones. Once you create a release, the release page itself will have an "Upload file" link.

To do this from a terminal, you can grab `lptools` from bzr, with `bzr branch lp:lptools` and use the `lp-project-upload` contained within, to upload a file to a project release. It can upload a file to a project, and create a new milestone and release for the upload. I'm not sure if it allows uploading to an existing milestone, or  uploading additional files to an existing milestone, though.

Comment: My bad! I forgot to state that I'm interested in command line procedure of doing it. I am familiar with LP web interface, but I was wondering if one might somehow do the same operations through a terminal.